# How to filter an array for all dictionaries that are within the same family or hierarchy as a certain dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have an array where dictionaries are within different 'families'. It's determined whether a dictionary falls within a certain family by it being 'related' to the dictionary at the top of the hierarchy.

For example, below is an array with each dictionary having a parent id that refers to another dictionary.

```
array = [{'id':'a','parent_id':'None'},{'id':'b','parent_id':'a'},{'id':'c','parent_id':'b'},{'id':'e','parent_id':'a'},{'id':'d','parent_id':'c'},{'id':'f','parent_id':'ZZZ'}]
```

`{'id':'c','parent_id':'b'}` is within the same family as `{'id':'a','parent_id':'None'}` because `{'id':'c','parent_id':'b'}` refers to `{'id':'b','parent_id':'a'}` which refers to `{'id':'a','parent_id':'None'}`

How do I filter this array for all dictionaries that are related to `{'id':'a','parent_id':'None'}`?

My Attempt

```
def children_return(D,array):
    return filter(lambda Dict: D['id'] == Dict['parent_id'] ,array)

def offspring_return(D,array):
    offspring = []
    subli = children_return(D,array)
    offspring.extend(subli)
    for Dict in subli:
        sub = children_return(Dict,array)
        offspring.extend(sub)
    return offspring



offspring_return({'id':'a','parent_id':'None'},array)

>> [{'id':'b','parent_id':'a'},{'id':'c','parent_id':'b'},{'id':'e','parent_id':'a'}]
```

However, that misses `{'id':'d','parent_id':'c'}`. I'd like to be able to create a function that can pull the infinite generations forward instead of only the children and grand children. The non-preferable solution is to write a ton of for loops.

The result should be the following:

```
[{'id':'b','parent_id':'a'},{'id':'c','parent_id':'b'},{'id':'d','parent_id':'c'},{'id':'e','parent_id':'a'}]
```

I think the solution is to use a while loop and utilize `children_return` function to be continuously done on it's result until it's result is empty for each. I can't seem to write this function though.

Comment: Note that `True if D['id'] == Dict['parent_id'] else False` can be shortened to `D['id'] == Dict['parent_id']`. Also, what is `Dict` referencing inside `children_return`?

Comment: I've updated for your suggestion and fixed for the typo that caused the confusion with what Dict was referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can literally change one name in your code and it will work:

```
array = [{'id':'a','parent_id':'None'},{'id':'b','parent_id':'a'},{'id':'c','parent_id':'b'},{'id':'e','parent_id':'a'},{'id':'d','parent_id':'c'},{'id':'f','parent_id':'ZZZ'}]

def children_return(D,array):
    return filter(lambda Dict: D['id'] == Dict['parent_id'] ,array)

def offspring_return(D,array):
    offspring = []
    subli = children_return(D,array)
    offspring.extend(subli)
    for Dict in subli:
        sub = offspring_return(Dict,array)
        offspring.extend(sub)
    return offspring

print(offspring_return({'id':'a','parent_id':'None'},array))
```

I'm not sure if you realized how close you were, but the only thing I did was change the call to `children_return` to a recursive call to `offspring_return`.

Comment: Thanks! I did feel close, but the concept of a recursion and the function referring to itself is a new one to me, but this exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution, which uses recursion but is pretty inefficient (I hope you're not looking for performance).

```
array = [
    {'id':'a','parent_id':'None'},
    {'id':'b','parent_id':'a'},
    {'id':'c','parent_id':'b'},
    {'id':'e','parent_id':'a'},
    {'id':'d','parent_id':'c'},
    {'id':'f','parent_id':'ZZZ'}
]

def get_node(array, id):
    for a in array:
        if a['id'] == id:
            return a

def related_to(array, node_a, node_b):
    # if node_a and node_b have a common ancestor, then they are related    
    if node_a == node_b:
        return True

    if node_a is None or node_b is None:
        return False

    if node_a['parent_id'] == 'None' and node_b['parent_id'] == 'None':
        return False

    if node_a['parent_id'] != 'None':
        return related_to(array, get_node(array, node_a['parent_id']), node_b)
    elif node_b['parent_id'] != 'None':
        return related_to(array, node_a, get_node(array, node_b['parent_id']))

def family(array, id):
    # return all the dicts that are related to id
    return [a for a in array if related_to(array, get_node(array, id), a)]

print(family(array, 'c'))
```

Which returns, as expected: `[{'id': 'a', 'parent_id': 'None'}, {'id': 'b', 'parent_id': 'a'}, {'id': 'c', 'parent_id': 'b'}, {'id': 'e', 'parent_id': 'a'}, {'id': 'd', 'parent_id': 'c'}]`